# Font issues with Chunks/Phrase in iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

I'm filling in the form fields of a PDF Template, and all is good.
Radio buttons, Check boxes, and plain text in the fields are all working well with the correct font.

I have a couple of fields where I need to strikethrough part of the text.

For example:   From <strike>Eur22.50</strike> to Eur18.00

So I assumed I needed to split the text into Chunks, apply different Fonts to each Chunk, and create a Phrase from them.

The issue is that the normal text (not the strikethrough) is not using the Font I am assigning.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
const Int32 FONT_SIZE = 8;
BaseFont _font = GetFont(BaseFont.CP1257);
Font _standardFont = new Font(_font, FONT_SIZE, Font.DEFAULTSIZE);
Font _strikethroughFont = new Font(_font, FONT_SIZE, Font.STRIKETHRU);

var c1 = new Chunk("From ", _standardFont);
var c2 = new Chunk(originalPrice.ToString("c", _culture), _strikethroughFont);
var c3 = new Chunk(String.Format(" to {0}", finalPrice.ToString("c", _culture)), _standardFont);
AddText("Abonnement_16", new [] {c1,c2,c3}, PdfContentByte.ALIGN_RIGHT);
```

This is the method that doesn't seem to be working:

```
private void AddText(String fieldName, IEnumerable<Chunk> textChunks, Int32 align) {
    var pos = _pdfstamper.AcroFields.GetFieldPositions(fieldName)[0].position;
    var phrase = new Phrase();

    foreach (var chunk in textChunks) phrase.Add(chunk);

    var ct = new ColumnText(_content);
    ct.SetSimpleColumn(pos.Left, pos.Bottom, pos.Right, pos.Top, 0, align);
    ct.AddElement(phrase);
    ct.Go();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What isn't working? Please note that nothing will be added to the document if the content doesn't fit the rectangle. The return value of the `Go()` method gives you that information.

Comment: Hi Bruno, I added an example to my post. The strikethrough part is showing up correctly and in the correct font. But the text before and after it are in a much larger font.

Comment: Ah, nevermind. This can be closed. It works fine as is, I was calling the wrong constructor in my code where the Font size was not set.